# Why am I getting this error after adding the liquibase configuration to my spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

I am pretty new to using liquibase for database migration and I was following this article https://dzone.com/articles/easy-database-migration-with-liquibase for adding liquibase to my spring boot application. Kindly help nudge me in the right direction as I did make the ID field in the schema not nullable.

This is the error log.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'staffController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'staffService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'staffServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'staffRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'staffRepositoryImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jdbcTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
    INSERT INTO PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) VALUES (NULL, NULL, 'classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml', NOW(), 1, '8:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e', 'empty', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '4.5.0', '9921389654') [23502-200] [Failed SQL: (23502) INSERT INTO PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) VALUES (NULL, NULL, 'classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml', NOW(), 1, '8:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e', 'empty', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '4.5.0', '9921389654')]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.oze.hospitalservice.HospitalServiceApplication.main(HospitalServiceApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'staffServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'staffRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'staffRepositoryImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jdbcTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
    INSERT INTO PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) VALUES (NULL, NULL, 'classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml', NOW(), 1, '8:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e', 'empty', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '4.5.0', '9921389654') [23502-200] [Failed SQL: (23502) INSERT INTO PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) VALUES (NULL, NULL, 'classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml', NOW(), 1, '8:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e', 'empty', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '4.5.0', '9921389654')]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'staffRepositoryImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jdbcTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
    INSERT INTO PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) VALUES (NULL, NULL, 'classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml', NOW(), 1, '8:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e', 'empty', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '4.5.0', '9921389654') [23502-200] [Failed SQL: (23502) INSERT INTO PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) VALUES (NULL, NULL, 'classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml', NOW(), 1, '8:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e', 'empty', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '4.5.0', '9921389654')]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        ... 34 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
    INSERT INTO PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) VALUES (NULL, NULL, 'classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml', NOW(), 1, '8:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e', 'empty', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '4.5.0', '9921389654') [23502-200] [Failed SQL: (23502) INSERT INTO PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) VALUES (NULL, NULL, 'classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml', NOW(), 1, '8:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e', 'empty', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '4.5.0', '9921389654')]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        ... 48 common frames omitted
    Caused by: liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
    INSERT INTO PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) VALUES (NULL, NULL, 'classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml', NOW(), 1, '8:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e', 'empty', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '4.5.0', '9921389654') [23502-200] [Failed SQL: (23502) INSERT INTO PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) VALUES (NULL, NULL, 'classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml', NOW(), 1, '8:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e', 'empty', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '4.5.0', '9921389654')]
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:124) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Liquibase.lambda$null$0(Liquibase.java:265) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:177) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:186) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:176) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:155) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:239) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Liquibase.lambda$update$1(Liquibase.java:264) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:177) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:186) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:176) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:155) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Liquibase.runInScope(Liquibase.java:2404) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:211) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:197) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:314) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:269) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        ... 60 common frames omitted
    Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
    INSERT INTO PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) VALUES (NULL, NULL, 'classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml', NOW(), 1, '8:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e', 'empty', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '4.5.0', '9921389654') [23502-200] [Failed SQL: (23502) INSERT INTO PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) VALUES (NULL, NULL, 'classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml', NOW(), 1, '8:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e', 'empty', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '4.5.0', '9921389654')]
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:393) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:82) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:150) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:134) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.changelog.StandardChangeLogHistoryService.setExecType(StandardChangeLogHistoryService.java:391) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.markChangeSetExecStatus(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1136) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:60) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator$2.lambda$null$0(ChangeLogIterator.java:111) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:177) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:186) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:176) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:155) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator$2.lambda$run$1(ChangeLogIterator.java:110) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:177) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:186) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:176) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:155) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:239) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator$2.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:94) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:177) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:186) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:176) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:155) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:239) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:243) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:66) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        ... 78 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
    INSERT INTO PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) VALUES (NULL, NULL, 'classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml', NOW(), 1, '8:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e', 'empty', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '4.5.0', '9921389654') [23502-200]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:459) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:374) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at org.h2.table.Table.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Table.java:845) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:187) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:151) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:198) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:251) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:228) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:201) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:389) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
        ... 103 common frames omitted
```

This is my changelog-master.yaml file

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
id: 1
author: gafar
changes:
  - createTable:
tableName: hospital_staff
columns:
  - column:
    name: id
    type: serial
    autoIncrement: true
    constraints:
      primaryKey: true
      nullable: false
  - column:
      name: name
      type: varchar(255)
      constraints:
        nullable: false
  - column:
      name: password
      type: text
      constraints:
        nullable: false
  - column:
      name: staff_id
      type: uuid
      default:
        uuid.random()
      constraints:
        nullable: false
  - column:
      name: registration_date
      type: date
      default:
        date.now()
      constraints:
        nullable: false
```

Answer (score 2):

there are multiple options to solve your here, which is a missing ID during the insert statement.

1. Let it be handled by DB: Depending on your database you not only have to set ID to not nullable, but also specify how the ID would be generated. For PostgreSQL you for example could specify the keyword 'SERIAL' in addition to your ID column specification. This would create a sequence and auto generate IDs.
2. Specify the IDs within your liquibase scripts as part of your insert statements. Just preferable, if there is an interest to referring to the IDs in a later stage of the script e.g. for specifying relations properly.